# Equivalence of limit at infinity and one-sided limit at zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined in $(0,a)$ for some $a>0$. Are the following two equivalent?

$$\lim_{x \to 0 \atop x>0} f(x) = l$$

$$\lim_{x \to +∞} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = l$$

This (and the equivalent for $x<0$ and $-∞$) seems to be assumed in the proofs of some theorems (for example the derivative of $\ln(x)$). I looked for a theorem stating this formally in wikipedia and in several books, but I didn't find such proposition.

Comment: Note that you should write $\ln x$ or $\ln(x)$, coded as \ln x or \ln(x).  This not only prevents italicization of $\ln$ but results in proper spacing in things like $a\ln b$.  Notice the spacing depends on the context: $a\ln b$ versus $a\ln(b)$. $\qquad$

Comment: @OP if you found the answer below helpful, you will get a reputation bonus if you accept it by clicking the checkmark below the answer's score (also it's good etiquette)

Answer (score 5):

The theorem might say the following:

> Suppose $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $g(x)$ differs from $g(a)$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.  Further suppose $\lim\limits_{u\to g(a)} f(u)$ exists.  Then
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = \lim_{u\to g(a)} f(u)
> $$

In this case you would have $g(x) = \dfrac 1 x$ and $a=+\infty$.

You could regard $+\infty$ as a point in a space $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$ and regard intervals $(m,+\infty]$ as its open neighborhoods and write a proof in the language of topology.  Or you could write an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: But he was asking about an equivalence. Your answer doesn't give this.

Comment: @zhw. : If two limits are equal to each other, then the statement that one of them is equal to $\ell$ is EQUIVALENT to the statement that the other is equal to $\ell.$ $\qquad$

Comment: OK, that comment of mine is badly stated. What I should have said is your theorem, as stated, is false. First, there is no necessary connection between $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ and $g(a).$ Perhaps you meant to require $g$ to be continuous at $a?$ But even if you require that, it still doesn't work. What if $g(x)\equiv g(a)$ near $a?$ Or merely that $g(x) = g(a)$ along a sequence of distinct $x$'s converging to $a.$ You run into trouble, because $f$ need not even be defined at $g(a).$ contd below ...

Comment: But even if $f$ was so defined, you still have trouble. The way out of this is to assume $g$ is continuous and injective in an open interval containing $a.$ Then your theorem will hold.

Comment: @zhw. : ok, I've revised it by adding the assumption of continuity of $g$ at $a$ and another assumption.  Injectivity is stronger than what is needed; I used a weaker assumption. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalent. Let's consider one direction: Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = L.$ We want to show $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(1/x) = L.$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $0 < x < \delta$ implies $|f(x)- L| <\epsilon.$ Set $M = 1/\delta.$ Then $x> M$ implies $0 < 1/x < 1/M = \delta.$ Hence $x> M$ implies $|f(1/x)- L|< \epsilon.$ This is what we needed to show.

I'll let you handle the converse; it's very much the same and will be more valuable to you if you do it than if I write and you nod.